# Conditional density boundary problems

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The definition of $Y$, given $X$, is uniform on the interval $[0,X]$. The marginal density of $X$ is

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x, & \text{for }0<x<1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$
Determine the conditional density of X given Y=y where positive.

For some reason the boundaries caused me problems when trying to find the marginal for $Y$ by integrating over $x$ from $0$ to $1$ apparently it's wrong. any hints anybody?

Comment: You're saying that the given answer isn't $\frac{1}{X}$?

Comment: Sorry I was asked to find the conditional density X given Y

Comment: The joint density would be 1/x * 2x =2 I tried to integrate it from 0 to 1 over dx to get marginal Y =2 which yields 1 for the final answer but the answer is 1/(1-y)

Comment: To find $f_Y$ you need $f_Y(y)=\int_{x=y}^1 2dx$.

Comment: can you explain why the lower bound has to be x=y?

Comment: Because it's impossible to have $X\lt Y$.

Comment: is it because the conditional density of Y is limited in 0 and X? thats how the range come from?

Comment: @natsu Yes, that's right.

Comment: One further question to make things clear, so I can deduce the range of Y even if the given range is in conditional right.

Comment: Well, yes, but those ranges should also translate to the joint density of $X,Y$. The range for that should be $0\lt X\lt 1$ and $0\lt Y\lt X$. (BTW, you should use @user in your comments).

Comment: @Mick A thanks so in conclusion the conditional densities y|x and x|y can translate to ranges for the overall boundaries y range and x range respectively. Sorry for being redundant but I always get wrong answers due to this

Comment: @natsu Yes. And when finding any density (marginal, conditional, joint) you should take care to note the ranges over which they apply. If you're not sure you have the range right, inegrate the density function over that range and makes sure it equals $1$.

Comment: @Mick A so when the conditional and marginal combined to have joint density the range would become 0<y<x<1 right?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that above.